# Seeking origin and original wording of a quotation attributed to Shakespeare

Tags: william-shakespeare, quote-source

During a Pub quiz early this week, a Shakespeare quote emerged in German translation, and I am keen to know the original wording and the work it stems from, or if it is possibly part of his notes.

This is my English translation of the line I heard in German:

> *Do not bemoan what cannot be altered but alter what is deplorable.*

Original German:

> *Beklage nicht, was nicht zu ändern ist,
>
> aber ändere, was zu beklagen ist.*

However, I can't find an equivalent line anywhere. Is there one? (I searched fruitlessly on several sites, e.g.,
https://myshakespeare.me/shakespeares-works/search-filter/)

[Note that this was [cross-posted on EL&U as well](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/613137/seeking-origin-and-original-wording-of-a-quotation-attributed-to-shakespeare)]

Comment: Not the same exact thing, but see Macbeth Act 3, Scene 2: _"You should not think about things you can’t change. What’s done is done."_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very similar (but not quite identical) to Ernst Ortlepp’s translation of *The Two Gentlemen of Verona*:

> **Proteus.** Cease to lament for that thou canst not help,
> And study help for that which thou lament’st.
> Time is the nurse and breeder of all good.
> Here if thou stay thou canst not see thy love;
> Besides, thy staying will abridge thy life.
>
> <sub>William Shakespeare (c. 1590). [*The Two Gentlemen of Verona*, act 3, scene 1](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/23043/pg23043-images.html#page123). Project Gutenberg.</sub>

> **Proteus.** Beklage nicht, was nicht zu ändern steht,
> Und ändre, wenn du kannst, was du beklagst.
> Die Zeit ist eine Amme alles Guten.
> Verweilst du hier, so droht dir nur Gefahr,
> Und deiner Liebe nüßt es nichts.
>
> <sub>Ernst Ortlepp (1838). [*W. Shakspeare’s dramatische Werke*, volume 1, p. 172](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Dramatische_Werke/bvwVAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA172). Stuttgart: L. F. Rieger.</sub>

The version of these lines in the question may derive from Ortlepp’s translation by the operation of memory and fallible recall; the [earliest instance I found on Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22Beklage+nicht,+was+nicht+zu+%C3%A4ndern+ist%22) is from 2002.